# Using Flash to export mov/quicktime video shows ghost images

Tags: flash, quicktime

I am trying to export a flash animation as a mov, so i can convert it for html5.  When I export the movie, the animation has artifacts in it, strange things do not erase correctly, they do not show when i view it in Flash, or when I view the exported flv file.

[image]

So as you can see, there is a 1/2 drawn image.  They round things are floating down, but for some reason, as they float down to stack, they leave behind some partial images.

***Has anyone seen and solved this before?***

settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but the solution (sometimes it's annoying) is to set the project frame rate to 30fps.

So, a tip, always start your projects with 30 fps.

Comment: Wow.  It took a while, but I am glad you found the question!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quicktime export out of Flash does not (never has and never will) work reliably.

To get the best results I would recommend exporting a PNG (i.e. lossless) sequence and then use another tool to convert that image sequence into a movie file. The only drawback with this is that the animation cannot contain `MovieClip` type of symbols, but you need to work with `Graphic`s instead (but you'll have that problem with swf2mov as well).

Tools (costly) that can be used for this are for example Quicktime Pro (which is discontinued unfortunately) or Adobe After Effects for example.

In case you are some kind of h4x0r you can use FFMPEG (which is for free).

Comment: That is great advice, FFMPEG works to make the video, but then you need to edit the video to add back in the sound, and that can be tricky for some movies.  I am also going to explore after effects, if that works I might buy it.

Comment: After Effects will do this in no time, yet it is really expensive. In case your FLA only consists of one scene you could also just export an additional .aiff from Flash and then use FFMPEG to mux it with the video track that you generated from the image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can only be resolved by setting key frame to lower rate than 24. Try lowering down to 1. The video will be much bigger (MUCH bigger), but you shouldn't have any artifacts leftover. If that method succeds, try altering the key frame to a rate you don't see the artifacts after render. Try 10. And step by step you will find a key freme rate that will not show artifacts and the video will be of optimal size.

Comment: a framerate of 1?  Thats 1 frame per second, no?